# Python: Json file become empty

Tags: python

Here is my code of accessing&editing the file:

```
    def edit_default_settings(self, setting_type, value):
        with open("cam_settings.json", "r") as f:
            cam_settings = json.load(f)

        cam_settings[setting_type] = value
        
        with open("cam_settings.json", 'w') as f:
            json.dump(cam_settings, f, indent=4)
```

I use It in a program that runs for several hours in a day, and once in a ~week I'm noticing, that cam_settings.json file becoming empty (literally empty, the file explorer shows 0 bytes), but  can't imagine how that is possible

Would be glad to hear some comments on what could go wrong

Comment: What is "empty" here? An empty file, or an empty JSON structure inside a file? (That is, `[]` or `{}`.)

Comment: @9769953 Yeah, I shold clarify that. Empty It means fully empty, like 0 bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any issues with the code itself, but there can be an issue with the execution environment. Are you running the code in a multi-threaded environment or running multiple instances of the same program at once?

This situation can arise if this code is executed parallelly and multiple threads/processes try to access the file at the same time. Try logging each time the function was executed and if the function was executed successfully. Try exception handlers and error logging.

If this is a problem, using buffers or singleton pattern can solve the issue.

Comment: Yeah, this is the only one reason I could imagine. The second read in a row will return an empty string which will be written to the file. My script is on auto-start, so probably I forgot to kill the program before starting the script manually, thanks. Will use approach with os.replace that @Dan Getz suggested below.

Answer (score 2):

As @Chels said, the file is truncated when it's opened with `'w'`. That doesn't explain why it stays that way; I can only imagine that happening if your code crashed. Maybe you need to check logs for code crashes (or change how your code is run so that crash reasons get logged, if they aren't).

But there's a way to make this process safer in case of crashes. Write to a separate file and then replace the old file with the new file, only after the new file is fully written. You can use [`os.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace) for this. You could do this simply with a differently-named file:

```
with open(".cam_settings.json.tmp", 'w') as f:
    json.dump(cam_settings, f, indent=4)
os.replace(".cam_settings.json.tmp", "cam_settings.json")
```

Or you could use a temporary file from the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

When openning a file with the `"w"` parameter, everytime you will write to it, the content of the file will be erased. (You will actually replace what's written already).

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but could be one of the reasons why "cam_settings.json" becomes empty after the call of `open("cam_settings.json", 'w')`!

In such a case, to append some text, use the `"a"` parameter, as:

```
open("cam_settings.json", 'a')
```

Comment: But then `json.load(f)` wouldn't work the next time around.

Comment: You might want to try and use "a+" parameter, which will allow you to read and append at the same time.

Comment: But they aren't trying to append anything. Look at the original question: they're trying to change part of a JSON object stored in the file.